# PyautoGUI- How to use If - Else with pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen

Tags: python, pyautogui

Essentially I want my Python script to perform this...

```
x = True
if x  == True:
    print('Congratulations, you won!')
else:
    print('I'm sorry but you lost.')
```

with this...

```
a, b = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('~/home/file_01.png', region=(1065,250,385,700), confidence=0.9)
```

In other words, how can I have my script check to see if PyautoGUI has successfully located the center of `~/home/file_01.png`?

See, about 95% of the time the following works correctly....

```
a, b = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('~/home/file_01.png', region=(1065,250,385,700), confidence=0.9)
```

But about 5% of the time `~/home/file_01.png` does not exist. In those cases my script stops and throws off the following error message...

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Instead of having my script stops in cases when `~/home/file_01.png` does not exist I would prefer that my script skip that instance. In other words, instead of stopping I want my script to ignore cases when `~/home/file_01.png` does not exist.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 2):

You could first check if `~/home/file_01.png` exists before executing your statement, like so:

```
import os
    
if os.path.exists("~/home/file_01.png"):
    a, b = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("~/home/file_01.png", region=(1065,250,385,700), confidence=0.9)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply to me. I added `print("The image was found.")` immediately below `a, b = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("~/home/file_01.png", region=(1065,250,385,700), confidence=0.9)` but `The image was found.` did not print out in my terminal when I ran the code you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyautogui

try:
    a, b = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('/home/file_01.png')

except:
    print("I'm sorry but you lost.")

else:
    print("Congratulations, you won!")



#use try except to remove the Fatal Error
```